# 1.3mm vs 1.27mm pad pitch on a MOSFET

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I have a layout that was done out of house and the pitch of a IC is listed on the datasheet as 1.27mm. The layout service constructed the IC in imperial and when Altium converted the imperial to metric, the pitch became 1.3mm instead of 1.27mm

The component in question is a CSD16325Q5  http://www.ti.com/product/CSD16325Q5

Should I do a waiver and run the PCB?

Comment: It depends how many pins are in a row. It takes enough accumulated error for it to matter since nothing is every *exactly* anything to begin with.

Comment: AFAIK Altium would easily convert 0.05in to 1.27mm and not 1.3mm, are you sure that's what happened? (it takes more decimal places for Altium to start rounding)

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. There are only 5 pins so the accumulated error would be quite small. I have experienced the units conversion error before so I didn't think to question the scale of the conversion error. I'll have to hunt this down a bit

Comment: I would take a more detailed look at this.  Any error in converting imperial to metric should not be cumulative.   The 'Gerber' data gives each pad a position so no pad should be more than 0.05mm from it's ideal position.  You can specify more digits of precision in the Gerber files if required.

Answer (score 0):

No, fix it now. If you waiver it, the assembly house will reject it and you will have more headaches and costs later.

Comment: It's fixed the right way. Thanks!